# knex promises - how to wait while two funcions finish their work

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

How to add code that will run only when both processes are completed?

```
normalise1();
normalise2();

function normalise1() {
    return knex("ingredients")
        .select("name", "id")
        .map(function (ingredient) {            
            var normalised_name = common.normalise(ingredient.name);
            knex('ingredients').where('id', ingredient.id).update({ name_normalised: normalised_name }).then();
        });
};

function normalise2() {
    return knex("synonyms")
        .select("synon_name as name", "id")
        .map(function (ingredient) {            
            var normalised_name = common.normalise(ingredient.name);
            knex('synonyms').where('id', ingredient.id).update({ synon_name_normalised: normalised_name }).then();
        });
};
```

I tried something like in different ways

```
Promise.all([normalise1(), normalise2()])
    .then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

but it didn't work. 
Basically console.log('Done') appears before all process is done. I believe that this is because of missing Promise part inside functions, but I cannot figure out exactly how.

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't give us enough to go on. What were you expecting, and what happened instead? *"Probably, because problem with function that do not return Promise"* Your code above certainly seems to, if my read of [the Knex documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-map) is correct.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Your edit invalidates an existing answer, which is generally a no-no on Stack Overflow. (Questions should not be moving targets.) Did your original code have the `()` or not?

Comment: I updated my question adding more information about my problem and also added () as I missed them by mistake. But still the problem is the same - I think that functions should return something , but not sure where and how (as never worked with Promises before).

Answer (score 2):

The functions are not called when passed to `Promise.all()`, no `Promise` is returned from `.map()`.

Call the functions and `return` `knex()` from `.map()` call, which may also require using `Promise.all()` within the function calls.

Comment: I now added () to functition call, but I didn't get  map part. Unfourtunately I am working with node only for two days.

Comment: No value is returned from `.map()` which would result in undefined values being returned from the function. Why do you chain `.then()` without passing a function?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to answer your question. My code is result of reading and watching examples, as well as trying to read documentation of knex and Promise, I do not understandy all this ycannheet. I thought that without then it never fires. I know that something it is wrong, but cannot figure out right way.

Comment: are you sayting that I have to remove then() and add return before knex update?

Comment: Not sure how Bluebird's `.map()` handles returned `Promise`s. Though some value needs to be `return`ed from `.map()`, even if you need to process the returned array further using `Promise.all()` at a chained `.then()`. Following the documentation something like `.map(function (ingredient) {            
            var normalised_name = common.normalise(ingredient.name);
            return knex('synonyms').where('id', ingredient.id).update({ synon_name_normalised: normalised_name });
        }).then(promises => Promise.all(promises))`

Comment: It's because without `await` or promise handling knex behave like query builder and spits back the query